# Whats an alternative for deleteFindMin for set of sets?

Tags: haskell, set

What's the equivalent function of `Data.Set.deleteFindMin` for usage on set of sets?
I created following type:

> type SofSes = Set.Set (Set.Set String)

All I need is to pick first set and return it like:

> {{firstSet},{secondSet},...,{n-thSet}} -> ({firstSet},{{secondSet},...,{n-thSet}})

`deleteFindMin`'s error message:

```
Couldn't match type `Set.Set String' with `[t0]'
    Expected type: Set.Set [t0]
      Actual type: Set.Set (Set.Set String)
```

My code:

```
reduce ts   
    | (Set.null (setW ts))==False = do                                   
        reduce (firstFor (Set.deleteFindMin (setW ts)) (getAlphabet ts)                                              
    | otherwise = ts


firstFor (a,w) (c:cs) ts                                                                   
    | null(c:cs)==False = do 
        secondFor (fromCtoA a c ts) ts                                            
    | otherwise =  ts

fromCtoA (a:as) c ts = ts  --function that is not finished yet (TODO)    

data KAutomat = KA
    { states :: Set.Set String
    , start :: KState
    , final :: Set.Set String
    , trans :: [Transition]
    , setW :: Set.Set (Set.Set String)
    , setP :: Set.Set (Set.Set String)
    } deriving (Eq)
```

Variable `ts` is of type KAutomat.

Comment: The fact that the set has sets in it is irrelevant. But you should probably use [`minView`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.11.0/docs/Data-Set.html#v:minView) instead of the partial  `deleteFindMin`.

Comment: Well `deleteFindMin` will give you one set and the rest. Be wary of what “first set” means as the typeclass provided ordering won’t necessarily give you the order you want.

Comment: But maybe what you really want is to fold.

Comment: @DanRobertson I don't actually care about order...I need to have pair - (firstSet, "othersSet") as described above.

Comment: So why doesn’t `deleteFindMin` or `minView` work?

Comment: @Dan I just edited the question.

Comment: Ok but that says your extracting one set from a set of sets and giving that to something that wants a list.

Comment: @Dan I added more of my code. Hope it's enough, in case it isn't, just tell me.

Comment: `fromCtoA` probably wants a String as it’s first argument but you pass a set of strings. One thing you could try is adding types before your functions and then the compiler can tell you if you’ve done something wrong. E.g `firstFor :: (Set.Set String, Set.Set (Set.Set String)) -> [???] -> KAutomat`. You should make sure that the types make sense for what the function does. Note that in `firstFor` you match a list as `(c:cs)` and then ask whether `not (null (c:cs))` but this will always hold: If the list is null then you’ll get a match failure trying to split it into `c` and `cs`.

Comment: You also don’t need (and so shouldn’t use) `do`.

Comment: @Dan May I know what's wrong with using `do` blocks?

Comment: When someone used to Haskell sees `do`, they think “what monad is this in and what is going to happen?” But in your case you aren’t really in a monad and so there is confusion in trying to work out why you are claiming to be (by writing `do`) and so it is harder to work out what your code is actually doing. In this case however the use or not of `do` appears to have relatively little impact on the codes readability.

Comment: I would find that `do` confusing for sure, for the reasons @DanRobertson described. You can't actually do anything nontrivial in that `do` block without a type error.

Comment: You must present an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); your current attempt does not meet this standard because it is not complete (many identifiers are not in scope), not verifiable (it does not parse, let alone get far enough in type checking to get your error), and probably not minimal (I doubt such a complicated `KAutomat` is needed to produce your error). Furthermore, you should include the *complete* error in the question, not just an excerpt.

Answer (score 1):

I can highlight one conflict in the code for you, though with the information given it's probably not possible to say what the right fix is. (I've left a comment on your question describing the effort I would expect you to put in that would make it possible to give more concrete help.)

Here is the conflict. You write

```
fromCtoA (a:as) c ts = ts
```

from which, since `a:as` can only be a list, we conclude that `fromCtoA` must take a list as its first argument. You also write:

```
reduce ... = ... firstFor (Set.deleteFindMin (setW ts)) ...
firstFor (a,w) ... = ... fromCtoA a ...
```

Since `setW` returns a `Set (Set String)`, the `deleteFindMin` call will return a `(Set String, Set (Set String))`, and so `a` will be a `Set String`, from which we conclude that `fromCtoA` must accept a `Set String` as its first argument. This is not compatible with our previous conclusion that `fromCtoA` can only accept lists.